# Code can't be executed after running click method

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, eclipse

After being run click function , i don't know why but the next sendKeys function can't be executed. eclipse is getting stuck and after a while, i'm facing with "timeout waiting for page to load" error. What might be the reason causing this issue ?

I'm just respectively populating text boxes named "gsmno" and "customerlastname" after running click function which provides the concerned button to be clicked (these three actions are working fine), once i tried to type something else into same text box , nothing happens. Actually , no matter i do after click action, the codes i have written doesn't work. How can it be possible ?

Btw, i don't get the error like "not able to find element", just the code can't be executed. In addition, there's no problem about page loading after clicking the button.

```
    driver.switchTo().frame("cx");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='gsmno']")).sendKeys("5467024809");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='customerlastname']")).sendKeys("asdsad");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='bul']")).click();   
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='customerlastname']")).sendKeys("asdsad");
```

---

i have attached the screenshot including xml.

[image]

Comment: your text boxes are inside the `frame` so again try to switch into this frame then perform your next `sendkey` action

Comment: Post some html, and the error you are getting.